# Select is blank no matter what option i select

Tags: html, css

So I wrote the following code for a webapp to have a few select options:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-8"><h1 class="title">Topological Distance</h1></div>
     <div class="col-4">
          <select id="differenceMetric" name="differenceMetric" onchange="reload()">
                  <option value="bottleneck">Bottleneck</option>
                  <option value="wasserstein">Wasserstein</option>
          </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

However, when I load it in my webbrowser with Flask, the select is blank. When I click the dropdown and choose a new option, the white box for the select is still blank

This only happens in on my Windows computer. I use the Brave browser on both my windows and mac and the issue only occurs on the Windows Brave browser.

Any insight into why this might happen?

Comment: Can you show reload() code?

Comment: Maybe the problem was inside this method `reload()` double-check this function. Make sure, you can call this method when the users select the options box. Thanks

Comment: ```const reload = 
() => 
{
    checks(emotions)
    checks(subsections)

    getRequest
        (null)
        ('embedding')
        (
            jsonData => {
                currentData = jsonData
                update_chart('#chart')

                R.forEach
                (
                    slide,
                    R.range(0,6)
                )
            }
        )
    
}```

The reload code is the same on my mac and windows computer (see above)

Comment: The functionality still works fine. I can change the value of the select using the dropdown without issue. But the value doesnt display on the page for the selected option.

Comment: https://ibb.co/JkFYCg8

Here's a link to a screenshot I took of what displays on the page.

Comment: Can you show the CSS for the select? The screenshot looks like the select has the same forteground and background colors.

Comment: By the way, please edit the question and add the new code in there. Comments are not really suitable for showing code.